# Replicate lists into a dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a function that returns a list

```
myfoo = function() {return( list(a=runif(1), b=runif(1)) )}
```

**Edit: To be clear, I cannot change this function.**

And I want to run it many time and get the results in a tibble (or data.frame).

```
replicate(5, myfoo())
```

However, I can't figure out how to get the results into a data.frame.

I've tried `replicate(5, myfoo() %>% as.data.frame()) %>% bind_rows()`, but I get `Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names`

To be clear, what I want is a data.frame with:

```
a   b
123 234
432 547
...
```

Comment: Why not just return a data frame in the first place: `data.frame(a=runif(5), b=runif(5))`?

Comment: `data.frame(t(replicate(5, myfoo())))`. Or if you prefer `replicate(5, myfoo()) %>% t %>% data.frame`

Comment: Or `replicate(5, myfoo(), simplify=FALSE) %>% 
  bind_rows`.

Comment: `myfoo <- function(n) data.frame(a=runif(n), b=runif(n)); myfoo(5)`

Comment: Since we're all just providing answers in the comments, maybe this too: `data.frame(matrix(runif(10), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("a", "b"))))`.

Comment: How about `replicate(5,do.call(rbind,lapply(myfoo()))`

Comment: @AlejandroAndrade why `lapply(myfoo())`? `argument "FUN" is missing, with no default`

Comment: Simpler: `do.call(rbind, replicate(5, myfoo(), simplify = FALSE))`, no need for `t` or others.

Comment: @eipi10 `replicate(5, myfoo(), simplify=FALSE) %>% bind_rows` solved it. Thank you.